# How to start creating iAds

Tags: javascript, safari

I'd like to learn how to create iAds. I already installed Xcode and the iAd Js.
In which environment to I make iAd Bundles? In Xcode?
Is there any guide on how to do this?

Comment: If you downloaded the Xcode beta, then you signed an NDA. You shouldn't be discussing this on a public forum until it has been publicly released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that the WWDC 2010 videos are [available for free](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/), I highly recommend watching Sessions 510 and 511, Creating Content With iAd JS, Part 1 and 2.

Answer (score 2):

There is a recently published guide on the iPhone Dev Center - just search for "Creating iAd Rich Media Ads for iOS Applications".  There is also a new sample iAd, SpaceTours, which seems to follow all of what is discussed in the guide.  This looks like a great place to start.

Next question: when will we be allowed to publish these in the iAd network for our clients? :-)

Enjoy.  Andrew

Answer (score 1):

The readme guide is bundled with the iAd JS download